# jquery: generate numbers in listbox

Tags: jquery, listbox, numbers

First, is it possible to create inputs like this with textarea or other element?

[image: number box]

And how could generate infinite numbers with jquery? (adding and subtracting)

I hope your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a "spinner" control and is not a native HTML object. You need to use JavaScript to make this work.

There are [several](http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/UI/spinner/spinner.html) [plug-ins](http://jquery.anantanandgupta.net/plugins/jQuerySpinnerControl/demo/1/) for jQuery that can do this for you.

Basically it's a textbox with two links beside it. Scripting handles the rest.